# patch not getting pushed to gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

While we are trying to push a patch we are getting the following error:

> error: failed to push some refs to
> 'ssh://git_bare_repo@10.20.88.250/home/ferrari_users/git_bare_repo/android_m/hlos/platform/frameworks/base'
>
> hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its
>
> remote hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the
>
> remote changes hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again. hint:
>
> See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

When I debugged I found a reference of gerrit commit which is actually abondoned through gerrit but is not getting reflected in Git.

We could still see a reference in **platform/frameworks/base.git/info/refs**

> eec90465656f3426cd5a45e5333cec90f07982c1        refs/changes/68/1968/1

So first question is if we abandon any patch will the entry still be present in refs folder and is there any file which lists the abondoned patches?

I think this is the reason why the specific project cant be synced-up and we are unable to push a new change.

Git pull and git checkout, points to last commit patch which has been successfully merged through Gerrit.

I tried to do a forced push using **git push -f origin HEAD:refs/for/8939_ferrari_main** It showed that the patch push  was successful and can see its entry in **frameworks/base.git/info/refs**

> cdd319b12cc422541b101e25470317ca28ddf6bc
> refs/for/8939_ferrari_main

but it is not getting listed in gerrit.
Is there any way to delete this patch from the git bare repo, since it is not getting listed in Gerrit.

Will appreciate if any pointers can be shared to resolve the issue.

---

Edit

**Is there any way to reset the git bare repo to any specific tags?**

Comment: The abandoned change is not the cause. Gerrit preserves abandoned changes and refs like `refs/changes/68/1968/1` forever, because Gerrit allows to "restore" an abandoned change. If a branch `foo` has been updated by `git push -f`, then the new commits are definitely not reviewed. `git push -f` indicates a direct push which doesn't create Gerrit entries for new commits. Only commits pushed by "git push origin foo:**refs/for/foo**" can be reviewed and have Gerrit entries.

Comment: sorry for the confusion the command used for push is: git push -f origin HEAD:refs/for/8939_ferrari_main. by using this command the repo sync is still not able to sync the code with latest patch.

Comment: From the error I guess the local branch is behind the remote branch. There might be no new local commits. Try `git fetch origin 8939_ferrari_main && git log FETCH_HEAD...HEAD` and see if any commits are printed. If none, you don't have to push the local branch because the remote branch has every commit of the local one.

Comment: Thanks Elpiekay, the output of command git fetch origin 8939_ferrari_main && git log FETCH_HEAD...HEAD shows nothing.  But I am trying to push a new commit even for that we are getting the same error of fast-forwards

Comment: Suppose the new commit is xxxxxx. What does the command `git fetch origin 8939_ferrari_main && git merge-base xxxxxx FETCH_HEAD` print? If it's right xxxxxx, then it's not "new" to the remote 8939_ferrari_main.

Comment: the output refers to commit-id which is referring to last commit in the codebase, not the one we are trying to push.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174934/discussion-between-anshul-and-elpiekay).

Answer (score 0):

To reset the bare repo to a certain  TAG , you need to have `force push` access on the refs/heads/BRANCH.

#### WARING this will make you loose the commits done after the tag!

```
git clone <REPO>
git checkout master
git reset --hard <TAG>
git push --force origin HEAD:refs/heads/master
```

Comment: Thanks, Tried but to no use. My biggest concern is the patches are not getting routed to Gerrit although there are entries in the bare repo of codebase

Comment: @Anshul if you can't find changes on gerrit for commits that are merged in the bare repo, this means, that when pushing you didn't use the magic references `refs/for/BRANCH` or `refs/drafts/BRANCH` when pushing, you can actually bypass gerrit if you have write on `refs/heads/* and push directly to the bare repo`